# Fatima Mahal as heritage site

Tags: plot-explanation, gulabo-sitabo

At the end of [Gulabo Sitabo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulabo_Sitabo), where Abdul Rehman became the owner of Fatima Mahal, why can't Gyanesh Shukla impose a government order to make the mansion a heritage site?

Comment: why uncover the ending? @BcotWEB

Comment: Because right before that paragraph you already told people that you'll uncover it. We require questions to be understandable without spoiler blocks.

Comment: There is no need to hide the entire question in spoiler markup. Only title needs to be made spoiler-free

Answer (score 1):

In the movie, when Gyanesh Shukla tells which properties Government declares heritage - like if the owners do not have the money to restore the place and the place has historical values. Also, they need the owners sign for declaring it as Heritage Property.

When Abdul Rehman got the custody, First he was in London. So Gyanesh can not force him to sign the paper as easily he could force to Mirza. Also, we can see in the end, the Haveli was restored and he has that reach in the government body that Police itself was appointed as security guard. If Gyanesh tried to declare it as heritage property, he could even fight a case in court and prove that the evidence that Gyanesh has set up (like the brick is only 20% match of heritage) is falsified and the Haveli is not a heritage property.